# How to load authenticated page inside tableau web page object?

Tags: tableau-api, dreamfactory

I want to load a web authenticated application inside tableau web page object, but it should automatically use some data and authenticate and load the page.
OR
May be anyway to authenticate the same tableau logged in user to my application which is loading inside web page object.

Comment: What authentication method is your embedded web application using?

Comment: I am using a API which need authenticated session token to get and send with every request.

Comment: I have a dashboard that has a webpage on it. That webpage requires authentication. I am not aware of any way to do any sort of pass through authentication like you describe. My users just log in to the app in the web page box on the dashboard and do whatever they need to. You may want to look at using Tableau embedded via the JavaScript API.